# Backup Daemon error - ops manager 3.4

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I have installed ops manager and setup the configuration for backup. When it tries to sync the mongodb deployment, it is giving an error as it could not find mongod in `/opt/mongodb/mms/mongodb-releases`.

Here is the error below, this is the error thrown by backup `daemon-   backup.jobs.590664394c9f732dd6c88b7c.tax`

```
Failed to start mongod

com.xgen.svc.brs.util.GenericMongoManager$MongoManagerConfigException: Could not find mongod. Found /opt/mongodb/mms/mongodb-releases/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.2.8/bin, but did not find /opt/mongodb/mms/mongodb-releases/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.2.8/bin/mongod.
com.xgen.svc.brs.util.GenericMongoManager$Purpose.<init>(GenericMongoManager.java:132)
com.xgen.svc.brs.util.MongoManager$MongoDPurpose.<init>(MongoManager.java:331)
com.xgen.svc.brs.util.MongoManager$HeadPurpose.<init>(MongoManager.java:477)
com.xgen.svc.brs.job.ReplicaSetJob.startMongo(ReplicaSetJob.java:103)
com.xgen.svc.brs.job.ReplicaSetJob.startMongo(ReplicaSetJob.java:80)
com.xgen.svc.brs.job.IncrementalSyncJob.doWork(IncrementalSyncJob.java:82)
```

Can you please show how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Restart the backup daemon (only the backup daemon).
It should normally download the mongodb releases at the very beginning.

```
2017-05-05T00:00:47.558+0000 [MongoDbReleaseAutoDownload Thread] INFO  com.xgen.svc.brs.autoDownloader.MongoDbReleaseAutoDownloadThread [MongoDbReleaseAutoDownloadThread.java.runInternal:105] - MongoDbReleaseAutoDownload run completed.
```

If it does not work, look at the daemon log (by default */opt/mongodb/mms/logs/daemon.log*).

Comment: Hello bappr, Thank you for your reply. I have restarted the backup daemon but i see the same error. one thing I have noticed that my network is not allowing to get downloads from https://fastdl.mongodb.com. so i have downloaded manually .tgz files and loaded in mongodb-releases directory. but it still says it can find version but could not find mongod file in bin directory.

Comment: what would be the owner to access the directories. currently i have changed owner to mongdb-mms

Comment: [root@mongodb-210653269-3-215007935 mongodb-releases]# ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms 86 May  4 20:55 mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.2.8
drwxr-xr-x 3 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms 86 May  4 17:42 mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.4.4

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 3 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms 86 May  4 20:55 mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.2.8    
drwxr-xr-x 3 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms 86 May  4 17:42 mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.4.4

Comment: I guess you don't have access to internet.
You can follow the instructions here https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/configure-local-mode/ to configure your Ops Manager in local mode.

Comment: Hello,  I have configured backup agent and configured locally instead of accessing internet. It worked with no errors. But I see different issue here , it tails the oplog but my data is worth of only bytes for now.  so my question here is , is back agent waits till it gets the 10MB of data oplog slices before it transfer to backup blockstore? I see there are no errors but i dont see any snapshots created.  can you please confirm that backup agents waits till it gets 10MB worth of data size before it creates a shanpshot?

Comment: No it does not wait. I am using last version of Ops Manager, and I can get a snapshot with just 2 or 3 tight data... Is the backup complete in OpsManager? What are in the logs of the backup daemon and in the the logs of the backup agent?

Comment: Hello bappr, I am seeing a different error regarding authorization in backup. it says group id is not authorized to create indexes on backing data blockstore. can you please tell me what is the user it is trying to create indexes on blockstore? Also i could not start the backup due to this error? i am not sure where i am doing wrong and could not debug. i am copying the error message in next comment.

Comment: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on 590664394c9f732dd6c88b7c to execute command { createIndexes: "oplog_tax", indexes: [ { key: { groupId: 1, rsId: 1, valid: 1, end: 1, _id: 1 }, name: "groupId_1_rsId_1_valid_1_end_1__id_1", ns: "590664394c9f732dd6c88b7c.oplog_tax", background: true } ] }' on server mongodb-210653269-1-215007920.prod.item-taxability.boftm.ndcprod5.prod.walmart.com:27017.

Comment: How did you manage your blockstore? using OpsManager or manually? If manually, the authentication must be enabled but the credentials are not set in OpsManager.

Comment: I am also using Ops Manager version 4. Backup daemon is running.Head database is configured. Backup agent runs where replicaset is running. I would like to know when the initial sync starts. And how to create backup job.